# How Can I Speed My C++ Program Up?

Tags: c++, optimization, vector

Basically I am relearning C++ and decided to create a lotto number generator.
The code creates the ticket and if that ticket does not already exist, it is added to a vector to store every possible combination.

The program works, but its just far too slow, adding an entry roughly every second, and It will get slower as it finds it more difficult to add unique combinations out of over 13 million possible combinations.

Anyway here is my code, any optimization tips would appreciated:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

vector<string> lottoCombos;

const int NUMBERS_PER_TICKET = 6;
const int NUMBERS = 49;
const int POSSIBLE_COMBOS = 13983816;

string createTicket();
void startUp();
void getAllCombinations();

int main()
{
    lottoCombos.reserve(POSSIBLE_COMBOS);
    cout<< "Random Ticket: "<< createTicket()<< endl;

    getAllCombinations();

    for (int i = 0; i < POSSIBLE_COMBOS; i++)
    {
        cout << endl << lottoCombos[i];
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

string createTicket()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    vector<int> ticket;
    vector<int> numbers;
    vector<int>::iterator numberIterator;

    //ADD AVAILABLE NUMBERS TO VECTOR
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBERS; i++)
    {
        numbers.push_back(i + 1);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < NUMBERS_PER_TICKET; j++)
    {
        int ticketNumber = rand() % numbers.size();
        numberIterator = numbers.begin()+ ticketNumber;
        int nm = *numberIterator;
        numbers.erase(numberIterator);
        ticket.push_back(nm);
    }
    sort(ticket.begin(), ticket.end());

    string result;
    ostringstream convert;
    convert << ticket[0] << ", " << ticket[1] << ", " << ticket[2] << ", " << ticket[3] << ", " << ticket[4] << ", " << ticket[5];
    result = convert.str();

    return result;
}

void getAllCombinations()
{
    int i = 0;
    cout << "Max Vector Size: " << lottoCombos.max_size() << endl;
    cout << "Creating Entries" << endl;

    while ( i != POSSIBLE_COMBOS )
    {
        bool matchFound = true;
        string newNumbers = createTicket();

        for (int j = 0; j < lottoCombos.size(); j++)
        {
            if ( newNumbers == lottoCombos[j] )
            {
                matchFound = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (matchFound != false)
        {
            lottoCombos.push_back(createTicket());
            i++;
            cout << "Entries: "<< i << endl;
        }
    }
    sort(lottoCombos.begin(), lottoCombos.end());
    cout << "\nCombination generation complete!!!\n\n";
}
```

Comment: If the program correctly, please migrate this question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: `const int POSSIBLE_COMBOS = NUMBERS * NUMBERS_PER_TICKET;`

Comment: Why do you need to store all the possible combinations?

Comment: You should look at `std::vector<bool>`.  Set a slot (bit) to true if the combination was found.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Isn't the vector specialization of bool slow due to the extreme packing? It looks like his vector size limits are known at compile time, so he could be using `std::bitset`

Comment: @RedAlert:  Since the vector size limits are known, the vector can be resized at the beginning.  The `std::bitset` may do extreme packing also.  A faster solution, if there is enough memory, is an array of `bool`; as long as it is not packed.

Comment: Why are you generating all possible combos by calling createTicket(), which is randomly generates a ticket? Also why after checking matchfound, another call to createTicket() is pushed back to lottoCombos?

Comment: @Tony J: Thank you for pointing the second call to creatTicket() when i push, i didnt realise i did that.

Comment: Your code is essentially generating all 13million combos RANDOMLY. Are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: I confess I am still learning and couldnt think of any other way of getting every possible combination other than generating the tickets at random and comparing them to the existing tickets.
As for why I want all the combinations, there is no big reason. I needed a quick starter program to make and i thought it would be an good idea to generate all the combinations and maybe take the program further by generating the most common combinations, if i found time etc.

Comment: But yeah, like i say, i am still learning. So any tips or assistance is appreciated :)

Comment: As @TonyJ says - generating all 13 million combos randomly isn't a good idea - imagine you have already got 12999999 and are trying to get the last 1, the chances of generating it each time are 1 in 13 million so most likely your code will have to iterate a lot before hitting upon the final ticket. Why not generate each ticket by following a logical sequence?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there are 49^6 possible combinations, aka almost 14 billion (with a b).  There aren't many computers that can fit that many values in RAM at once.... :)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, His algorithm is 49 choose 6, so 13million is correct.

Comment: oh, I see ... duplicate numbers aren't allowed.  Nevermind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason each lottery ticket is taking a second to generate is because you are misusing srand().  By calling srand(time(0)) every time createTicket() is called, you ensure that createTicket() returns the same numbers every time it is called, until the next time the value returned by time() changes, i.e. once per second.  So your reject-duplicates algorithm will almost always find a duplicate until the next second goes by.  You should move your srand(time(0)) call to the top of main() instead.

That said, there are perhaps larger issues to confront here:  my first question would be, is it really necessary to generate and store every possible lottery ticket?  (and if so, why?)  IIRC real lotteries don't do that when issuing a ticket; they just generate some random numbers and print them out (and if there are multiple winning tickets printed with the same numbers, the owners of those tickets share the prize money).

Assuming you do need to generate every possible lottery ticket for some reason, there are better ways to do it than randomly.  If you've ever watched the odometer increment while driving a car, you'll get the idea for how to do it linearly; just imagine an odometer with 6 wheels, where each wheel has 49 different possible positions it can be in (rather than the traditional 10).

Finally, a vector has O(N) lookup time, and if you are doing a lookup in the vector for every value you generate, then your algorithm has O(N^2) time, which is to say, it's going to get really slow really quickly as you generate more tickets.  So if you have to store all known tickets in a data structure, you should definitely use a data structure with quicker lookup times, for example a std::map or a std::unordered_set, or even a std::bitset as suggested by @RedAlert.